# Upgrading windows 8.1 to windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10

**I am upgrading my PC to windows 10. I have multiple Microsoft products installed on my PC such as Visual studio 2012 pro , Visual studio pro 2013 , Microsoft SQL server 2014 and Microsoft office 2010. I have a doubt that if after upgrading to windows 10 will these products work as previous without any problem or I have to install all of them separately again. I have created a ISO of WINDOWS 10 as my internet speed is low for big downloads so I can not go for windows update.** 
If the questions is not for this forum then please suggest the appropriate forum for my question not downvote it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thank you all for your response I will ask my question there :)

Comment: Why do you have VS2012 and 2013 installed side-by-side? Unless you need to Windows **8.0** (not 8.1) "Modern app" development then there is no reason to have 2012 installed.

Comment: @Dai I think 2012 is also still capable of creating Mango (WP7.5) apps, which is useful if you want to target old WP devices (some people still use WP7.x) but otherwise, yeah, no need for both.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I recommend against upgrade installations. While they are nominally supported, in practice they are much buggier and less well-tested than clean installs. They often exhibit bizarre behavior not seen otherwise, which is difficult to reproduce and hence will not be fixed.

With that said, none of the programs you list should have a problem running on Win10, and I would expect them to come through the upgrade safely. Office 2013 or 2016 will integrate with Win10 better than 2010 will, but any of them should run fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the answer. I have upgraded my windows by keeping all settings and file option. It is working fine. My all previous projects working correctly. It is working fine till now. I am now exploring Windows 10. :)